# how can I return multiple row counts

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have three entities, User, Rule, and Activity

with the following relationship, One rule has many activities (bidirectional)
Many users have many activities(bidirectional), the server is with spring using spring jpa

I want to show how many Activities has one user started but not finished from every rule, with SQL this query would return that from one rule

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_activity WHERE user_id=userId AND score<10 AND 
activity_id IN (SELECT id FROM activity WHERE rule_id=ruleId);
```

I could do that with JPQL, but how could  I return that count from every rule?
so I could have from every rule, how many activities has that User

if someone needs it I can provide java model code too.

tables are  User, Activity, Rule and User_Activity
[image: User table]

[image: Activity table]

[image: Rule table]

[image: User Activity table]

Comment: Could you show us the table structure? Without that it's impossible to guess at an answer. Some sample data would be helpful too...

Comment: added table estructure

Comment: hey, I deleted my answer as @nick already provided you with the working solution. I have no experience with translating queries to JPQL. We usually use MySQL syntax through hibernate without JPQL. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query is probably what you want. It finds all the activities associated with a given rule, then joins the users participating in that activity who have not finished it (I presume that's what score<10 indicates?)

```
SELECT r.id, u.id, COUNT(a.id)
FROM rule r
JOIN activity a ON a.rule_id = r.id
JOIN user_activity ua ON ua.activity_id = a.id AND ua.score < 10
JOIN user u ON u.id = ua.user_id
GROUP BY r.id, u.id
```

Obviously you can expand the `SELECT` to include things like the rule description and the user name etc.

I couldn't see any indication of what "activity complete" means so I've presumed it's that the score is less than 10. If that's not the case, you would need to change the join to `user_activity` appropriately.

Comment: This works on mysql! now I'm trying to transform it into JPQL

Comment: That's great. Sorry I can't help with the JPQL if you want to leave the question unaccepted to try and get a JPQL solution I don't mind.